# Install/compile for specific Silverlight build

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I updated Silverlight on my dev. machine, but clients still have older Silverlight version and they do not want to update.

Now I need to revert Silverlight 4 back to older version (50401). I tried to uninstall Silverlight and install older version, this required my to install developer tools, too.

No luck, still it requires newer version on clients machines. So I suppose real version is inside developer tools?

The question is, how do I make VS2010 to compile project for specific Silverlight 4 build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already stumbled on that kind of problem, and I had to re-install my sdk.

Check out that great [article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/28/keeping-your-silverlight-dev-environment-stable-through-service-releases.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+timheuer+%28Method+%7E+of+%7E+failed+by+Tim+Heuer%29) from Tim Heuer:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/28/keeping-your-silverlight-dev-environment-stable-through-service-releases.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+timheuer+%28Method+%7E+of+%7E+failed+by+Tim+Heuer%29

Comment: Thanks, what I needed was the link to the SDK.